# Facebook Comments box moderation on website not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have added fb comments box on my website http://www.ajinkyaxjs.com/learn.io/frontend-development-course.html
at footer. **Its visible, but I cannot moderate it.**

**Nither its visible in comments queue panel** https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments

Please note, Im using Angularjs to load comments box asynchronously, will that be an issue. If thats the case how do you explicitly load facebook SDK.

Below is present in my code:
HEAD

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="245629822267100" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.ajinkyaxjs.com/learn.io/frontend-development-course.html" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" >
```

And comments.html gets loaded with ng-include

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : '245629822267100',
            xfbml      : true,
            version    : 'v2.4'
        });
    };

    (function(d, s, id){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.ajinkyaxjs.com/learn.io/frontend-development-course.html" data-numposts="5"></div>
```

And fb debug keeps saying 'og:type' is missing, while I have already added it. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: `'ob:type'`? I only see `'og:type'`.

Comment: that was a typo. I meant og:type only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on main index.html page I had to add proper og meta tag though facebook comments was on some different page.